# Difference in `kbdrate`, `xset`, and GUI setting on Linux (Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

### `xset -q` output (relevant keyboard line only):

```
$ xset q | head -9 | tail +9
  auto repeat delay:  722    repeat rate:  17
```

So, you can clearly see that my keyboard setting is:

- keyboard repeat **delay = 722**
- keyboard repeat **rate = 17**

---

In Linux Mint 21.1 Vera Cinnamon there is this GUI for keyboard sensitivity:

[image: In Linux Mint 21.1 Vera Cinnamon there is this GUI for keyboard sensitivity]

While watching those values with, for example:

```
$ watch -n0.1 'xset q | head -9 | tail +9'
```

the changes done via GUI are reflected immediately.

---

I like my keyboard settings, they are rather slow, which I prefer.

Now, why this works in X (Cinnamon):

```
$ xset r rate 722 17
```

and this does not in X (Cinnamon):

```
$ sudo kbdrate --rate=17 --delay=722
Typematic Rate set to 16.0 cps (delay = 750 ms)
```

Does the first command (`xset`) work in X and the latter `kbdrate` only in a console (VT1,...)?